# SaaS, central database, database per user, or combination?

Tags: couchdb, saas, couchapp

Problem at hand is as follows:

- SaaS to keep maintenance records
- 95% of data would be specific to each user i.e. no need to be accessed by other users
- 5% of data shared (and contributed by all users), like parts that are used in maintenance
- SaaS to be delivered as CouchApp i.e. with public facing CouchDB

So I am torn between database per user, and single database for all users.

Database per user seems to offer much easier backup and maintenance, smaller data set, and easier access control. On the negative side how could I handle shared data?

Is it possible to have database per user, and one common database for shared information (parts)? Then replicate parts documents from all user databases to central one, from there back to all user databases? How to handle conflicts in that case (or even better avoid if possible)?

Or any much simpler approach? Or bite the bullet and go with just one central database?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the nature of the shared data, I guess. It seems natural to have filtered replication flowing from the user databases to the shared databases and unfiltered replication from the shared database to the user databases; I think that covers your requirements? It makes it so that each user only has to read/write from/to their specific database, while you can still distribute out the shared docs.

It may be easier to query from the shared database directly instead of replicating it back into the user databases, but that really depends on what kind of data would be in there.

Comment: well if I understand correctly if common parts are not replicated back to the user database I would not be able to combine them in views together with user data